# OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, mysql

I'm making a Timetable scheduler as a final year project. For the last two days, I'm getting an OutOfMemoryException. I have read a lot about the exception, and tried to increase the memory alloted through the -Xms and -Xmx options. None of these seem to work for me.

I profiled the project, and found that the maximum space was consumed by hashmap objects, and also by the MySQL connection. I have used a static connection as follows

```
public final class Connector
{
private static Connector connector;
Connection con;
String driverName;
String dbname;
String username;
String password;
String connString;

private Connector(){
    driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    dbname = "timegen";
    username = "root";
    password = "root";
    connString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + dbname;
    openConnection();
}

public void openConnection(){
    try{
        Class.forName(driverName);

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(connString, username, password);
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);

    }
}


public void terminateConnection(){
    try{
        con.close();
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

public static Connector createConnection() {

    if (connector == null){
        connector = new Connector();
    }

    return connector;
}

public Connection getCon() {
    return con;
}
public String getConnString() {
    return connString;
}

public void setConnString(String connString) {
    this.connString = connString;
}

}
```

This is the code for a class named MasterData, which is extended by all other classes that access the database

```
public class MasterData{
    static Connector con;
    static Statement st;

    MasterData(){
    try {
        con = Connector.createConnection();
        st = con.getCon().createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MasterData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }

    public Statement createStatement() throws SQLException{
        Statement st = con.getCon().createStatement();
        return st;       
    }
    public void closeConnection(){
        con.terminateConnection();
    }


}
```

An example of a class that uses this

```
public class Teacher extends MasterData{

int teacherid;
String teachername;
String subject;
String post;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Teacher{" + "teacherid=" + teacherid + ", teachername=" + teachername + ", 
post=" + post + ", subject=" + subject + '}';
}



public Teacher(int teacherid, String teachername,String subject, String post) {
    this.teacherid = teacherid;
    this.teachername = teachername;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.post = post;
}

public Teacher(String teachername) {
    this.teachername = teachername;
}

public Teacher(){}

public String display(){

    String s ="\nTeacher name = " + teachername
            + "\nSubject = " + subject
            + "\nPost = "+post;
    return s;
}


public ArrayList<String> getSubjectTeachers(String s){
    ArrayList<String> teachers = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select teachername from teacher where 
subject='"+s+"';");
        while(rs.next()){
            teachers.add(rs.getString(1));
        }
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    return teachers;
}

public List<Teacher> getFree()
{
   List<Teacher> lst = new ArrayList<Teacher>();
   try{
       ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from teacher where teacherid not 
in(select classteacher from division where classteacher!=null)");
       while(rs.next())
       {
            lst.add(new 
 Teacher(rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4)));
       }

   }catch(Exception e ){e.printStackTrace();}
   return lst;
}




public int getTeacherid() {
    return teacherid;
}

public void setTeacherid(int teacherid) {
    this.teacherid = teacherid;
}

public String getTeachername() {
    return teachername;
}

public void setTeachername(String teachername) {
    this.teachername = teachername;
}


public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

public String getPost() {
    return post;
}

public void setPost(String post) {
    this.post = post;
}

public boolean checkDuplicate(){
    try{
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from teacher where 
teachername='"+teachername+"';");
        if(rs.next())
            return true;

    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

         return false;

}

public boolean insert(){
    int t;
    try{
        t = st.executeUpdate("insert into teacher(teachername,subject,post)     
values('"+teachername+"','"+subject+"','"+post+"');");
        if(t!=0) return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;

    }
    return false;
}


public boolean delete(){
    int t;
    try{
        new AssignedTeacher().deleteTeacher(teacherid);
        t = st.executeUpdate("delete from teacher where teacherid="+teacherid+";");
        if(t!=0) return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;

    }
    return false;
}

public boolean update(){
    int t;
    try{
        t = st.executeUpdate("update teacher set teachername = '"+teachername+"',                  
subject='"+subject+"', post='"+post+"' where teacherid="+teacherid+";");

        if(t!=0) return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;

    }
    return false;
}

}
```

My intention was to create a single static connection for the entire program. It seems to work well. But is this the possible cause of the problem?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I'm not getting a null pointer exception.The entire program worked well, till I added a few more functions. Then I started getting on OutOfMemory Exception

Comment: Does the getter simply return `Connector`'s `Connection con` field?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29876/discussion-between-lifus-and-sotirios-delimanolis)

Comment: I edited the code, pasted a tested version. Also added an example of a class that extends MasterData. The openConnection() method is called only in the constructor of MasterData

Comment: @AartiRajan I would ask you to post a full stack trace of the exception. I don't see where you would get an OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: Also, are you sure its the SQL connection and not the HashMaps you mentioned? How much memory was each taking up?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating too many `Connection`s.

You may verify whether or not your connection [is valid](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid%28int%29) in your `openConnection` method You also may use some [Connection Pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool).

**EDIT:**

It seems to me that you've tried to implement [Active record pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) because there are `insert`, `delete`, `update` and `getSubjectTeachers` methods. Anyway, its is not always a good idea to [extend `Teacher` from `MasterData`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). As a side effect, new connections will be created for each instance of `MasterData`. `static Connection con` would be reassigned to new object but previous Connection will not be ever closed. Same holds with `MasterData#createStatement`.

Also, as greedybuddha pointed out, make sure that your `HashMap` are not reassigned in the same manner.

Comment: Would it help if I simply opened and closed a connection every time I query the database? And not use these two classes?

Comment: It's not really necessary. Are you allowed to reuse some external jars? If so, there are several good implementations available, e.g. [C3PO](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set these parameters as well:

```
-XX:PermSize
-XX:MaxPermSize
```

Comment: It looks like she tried it already _and tried to increase the memory alloted through the -Xms and -Xmx options_. Subsequent `OutOfMemoryError`s are only a matter of time since there are some issues in code.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that it's `PermGen space` error since `static` objects are still stored in the heap.